# AS3 Add array to another array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Example of the my problem.

```
 var array_1:Array = new Array();
 array_1[0] = [2,4,6,8];

 var array_2:array = new Array();
 array_2[0] = [10,12,14,16];
 array_2[1] = [18,20,22,24];

 // and the out come I want it to be is this  
 trace(array_1[0]) // 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,20,22,24

 // I did try  array_1[0] += array_2[0] but it didn't work currently
```

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Try `concat()` method : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#concat()

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 Fastest way to merge multiple arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551008/as3-fastest-way-to-merge-multiple-arrays)

Comment: There is also this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551008/as3-fastest-way-to-merge-multiple-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will perform what you are looking for and also allows you to add multiple rows of data to `array_1` or `array_2`

```
var array_1:Array = new Array();
array_1[0] = [2,4,6,8];

var array_2:Array = new Array();
array_2[0] = [10,12,14,16];
array_2[1] = [18,20,22,24];

var combinedArray:Array = new Array();
for( var i:int = 0; i < array_1.length; i++ ) {
    combinedArray = combinedArray.concat(array_1[i]);
}
for( i = 0; i < array_2.length; i++ ) {
    combinedArray = combinedArray.concat(array_2[i]);
}

trace(combinedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you can use the `concat` method:

```
 var array_1:Array = new Array();
 array_1[0] = [2,4,6,8];

 var array_2:array = new Array();
 array_2[0] = [10,12,14,16];
 array_2[1] = [18,20,22,24];

 array_1[0] = array_1[0].concat(array_2[0]).concat(array_2[1]);
```

This, of course, is very messy looking. I am wondering why you are storing arrays inside of other arrays for no discernible reason.

Comment: The messy reason is because array_2 is a temporary array which is likely to change a few times before it goes to the main array of array_1. < Thanks for the reply and the help